# c# classes format to send json data to android app

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, json

I have four tables:

1)tblcategory-This table contains all the top and sub categories

2)tblcatmapping-this table gives the category mapping.Means which category lies under which category

3)tblitem-This table contains all the menu items

4)tblitemmapping-This table contains the mapping details.Means which items lies under which category.

tblcategory snapshot:
[image]

tblcatmapping snapshot:

[image]

tblitem snapshot

[image]

tblitemmapping snapshot:

[image]

Now I want to send the entire data to android app in json format.I have prepared a rough json sample in which I want to send the data.

Json data sample

```
[
{
"CATID": "10001",
"CATNAME": "food",
"CATTYPE": "top",
"CATDESC": "contains different types of food",
"CATIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 11-41-29-food.jpg",
"CATSUBCAT": [
    {
        "CATID": "10002",
        "CATNAME": "veg",
        "CATTYPE": "sub",
        "CATDESC": "contains different drinks",
        "CATIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg",
        "CATSUBCAT": [
            {
                "CATID": "10004",
                "CATNAME": "nort-indian",
                "CATTYPE": "sub",
                "CATDESC": "contains different drinks",
                "CATIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg",
                "CATSUBCAT": [],
                "CATITEM": [
                    {
                        "ITEMID": "20002",
                        "ITEMNAME": "dosa",
                        "ITEMTYPE": "item",
                        "ITEMDESC": "contains different dosa",
                        "ITEMIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg"
                    },
                    {
                        "ITEMID": "20003",
                        "ITEMNAME": "idli",
                        "ITEMTYPE": "item",
                        "ITEMDESC": "contains different idli",
                        "ITEMIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "CATID": "10005",
                "CATNAME": "south-indian",
                "CATTYPE": "sub",
                "CATDESC": "contains different drinks",
                "CATIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg",
                "CATSUBCAT": [],
                "CATITEM": []
            }
        ],
        "CATITEM": []
    },
    {
        "CATID": "10003",
        "CATNAME": "non-veg",
        "CATTYPE": "sub",
        "CATDESC": "contains different drinks",
        "CATIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg",
        "CATSUBCAT": [
            {
                "CATID": "10004",
                "CATNAME": "nort-indian",
                "CATTYPE": "sub",
                "CATDESC": "contains different drinks",
                "CATIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg",
                "CATSUBCAT": [],
                "CATITEM": []
            },
            {
                "CATID": "10005",
                "CATNAME": "south-indian",
                "CATTYPE": "sub",
                "CATDESC": "contains different drinks",
                "CATIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg",
                "CATSUBCAT": [],
                "CATITEM": []
            }
        ],
        "CATITEM": []
    }
],
"CATITEM": []
},
{
"CATID": "10006",
"CATNAME": "beverages",
"CATTYPE": "top",
"CATDESC": "contains different drinks",
"CATIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg",
"CATSUBCAT": [
    {
        "CATID": "10007",
        "CATNAME": "alcholic-drinks",
        "CATTYPE": "top",
        "CATDESC": "contains different drinks",
        "CATIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg",
        "CATSUBCAT": [],
        "CATITEM": []
    },
    {
        "CATID": "10008",
        "CATNAME": "non-alcholic-drinks",
        "CATTYPE": "top",
        "CATDESC": "contains different drinks",
        "CATIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg",
        "CATSUBCAT": [],
        "CATITEM": []
    }
],
"CATTITEM": []
},
{
"CATID": "10009",
"CATNAME": "fast food",
"CATTYPE": "top",
"CATDESC": "contains various fast foods",
"CATIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-22-08-fastfood1.jpg",
"CATSUBCAT": [],
"CATITEM": [
    {
        "ITEMID": "20002",
        "ITEMNAME": "dosa",
        "ITEMTYPE": "item",
        "ITEMDESC": "contains different dosa",
        "ITEMIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "ITEMID": "20003",
        "ITEMNAME": "idli",
        "ITEMTYPE": "item",
        "ITEMDESC": "contains different idli",
        "ITEMIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\09-09-2013 12-15-19-beverages.jpeg"
    }
]
},
{
"CATID": "10015",
"CATNAME": "test",
"CATTYPE": "top",
"CATDESC": "contains test categories",
"CATIMGPATH": "Z:\\TFS workspace\\DineGenie - Dev\\DineGenie - Dev\\Filestore\\category\\19-09-2013 15-46-19-southindian2.png",
"CATSUBCAT": [],
"CATITEM": []
}
]
```

I can consider other format also.My main motive is to send all the category and item data with proper relationship depicted from the tblcatmapping and tblitemmapping.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I want the class structure or the way through c# coding by which I can send the entire data of four tables in json format

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct you want to see how the C# corresponding to your JSON would look like, If that's the case:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string CATID { get; set; }
    public string CATNAME { get; set; }
    public string CATTYPE { get; set; }
    public string CATDESC { get; set; }
    public string CATIMGPATH { get; set; }
    public List<object> CATSUBCAT { get; set; }
    public List<object> CATITEM { get; set; }
    public List<object> CATTITEM { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure you try: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Ya i have tried the above structure but i am not getting how to make a list of objects or suggest me what is the correct way to send my entire data in json format.I might have created wrong json sample

Comment: I have posted my question in other format also you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652140/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp.But i havent got the satisfactory answer so i posted it again with all the information of my tables.Please help me